# language independent: split a line with multiple repeating properties into multiple lines with each property only once

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vb6

I have lines such as the following:

```
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop3 value5#prop5 value6#prop5 value7#prop5 value8#prop2 value9
```

which means each property can be multiple times in the same line, in different positions with different values. I'm looking for a fast and efficient way to split that line into the corresponding amount of lines (in this case 12: 2x2x3 where each property with each value exists only once:

```
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value8

prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value8

prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value8

prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value8
```

There can be any amount of properties, which can be any time (>=1) in any order in each line.

This is really language independent but the current implementation of the parser is in vb6.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search for Cartesian product. Simplest implementation is probably by using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some Java code that generates the desired output. Hopefully you can translate it to VB6.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop3 value5#prop5 value6#prop5 value7#prop5 value8#prop2 value9";

    String[] pairs = input.split("#");

    // build a map of properties to values
    Map<String, List<String>> propValues = new TreeMap<>();
    for(String pair : pairs) 
    {
        String[] p = pair.split(" ");
        String prop = p[0];
        String value = p[1];

        List<String> values = propValues.get(prop);
        if(values == null) propValues.put(prop, values = new ArrayList<String>());
        values.add(value);
    }

    // create and fill an array with the number of values for each property
    int[] sizes = new int[propValues.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(String prop : propValues.keySet())
    {
        sizes[i++] = propValues.get(prop).size();
    }

    // create an array to hold the index of each value we're going to select
    // all array elements initialized to 0
    int[] idx = new int[sizes.length];

    // generate output
    while(true)
    {
        // print the output line, selecting the indexed value for each property
        int j=0;
        for(String prop : propValues.keySet())
        {
            String value = propValues.get(prop).get(idx[j++]);
            System.out.print(prop + " " + value);
            if(j < idx.length) System.out.print("#");
        }           
        System.out.println();

        // generate the next permutation of indexes
        int k=idx.length-1;
        for(; k>=0; k--)
        {
            idx[k]++;
            if(idx[k] < sizes[k]) break;
            idx[k] = 0;

            // This prints a blank line whenever the last property wraps around
            // Your example output has this, I'm not sure if it's significant
            if(k==idx.length-1) System.out.println();
        }

        // if the first index wrapped around then we're done
        if(k < 0) break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value8

prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value2#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value8

prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value3#prop4 value4#prop5 value8

prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value6
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value7
prop1 value1#prop2 value9#prop3 value5#prop4 value4#prop5 value8
```